# What RAM should I get for achieving dual channel on Thinkpad E14 gen 3?

Tags: memory

I recently bought a `Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen 3` with `AMD Ryzen 3 5300U with Radeon Graphics (8) @ 2.600GHz`. The laptop came with `8GB` soldered `RAM` preinstalled out of which I have `6822MiB` available to use. Now I want to buy a new `RAM` of preferably `8GB` and want to achieve dual channel. But I no experience with dual channel configurations and all. So I asking for some recommendation on what `RAM` hardware would be compatible with the current `RAM` I have. The current `RAM` specifications are as follows,

`dmidecode` output for `-t memory`

```
❯ sudo dmidecode -t memory
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 64 GB
        Error Information Handle: 0x0000
        Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0001
        Error Information Handle: 0x0007
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: Unknown
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: Unknown
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Null
        Serial Number: Null
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Null
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: Unknown
        Memory Technology: Unknown
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: Unknown
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: None
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0001
        Error Information Handle: 0x0009
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8 GB
        Form Factor: SODIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 3200 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Micron Technology
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: MY_PART_NUMBER_HERE
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 3200 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: DRAM
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 1, Hex 0x2C
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: 8 GB
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None
```

`lshw` output for `-C memory`

```
❯ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 1
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: [empty]
          product: Null
          vendor: Null
          physical id: 0
          serial: Null
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: MY_PART_NUMBER_HERE
          vendor: Micron Technology
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Corsair Vengeance Black 8GB 2400Mhz (https://nl.hardware.info/geheugenmodules.20/corsair-vengeance-black-8gb-ddr4-2400-cl16-sodimm.420300, Dutch review site) for around €40. Although it will slow down the onboard memory, they will work together in dual channel, which gives you a general memory speed improvement (a LOT if you currently see high memory usage because you also double the capacity).